# Reading BMP file without Bitmap class for learning purposes, issue with LockBits (C# with unsafe blocks)

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, unsafe

I have such Windows Forms project which reads a 24bit RGB BMP file. It all works fine except the method which prints the bitmap to form. There's a commented line of code, which totally replaces the whole loop below this line, but as comment states, it only works when rows in a file have no padding (for example, when I try to load desktop screenshot which is 1920x1080). But when I try to open any file where row size isn't divisible by four, the image looks weird - it becomes gray and pixels are shifted diagonally. So the question is, what am I doing wrong with assigning a pointer to my array, and why it works in some cases? Also some tips for improving code appreciated. Thanks!

```
    public sealed unsafe partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private byte[,,] imageData;
        private BMPHeader header;

        private readonly FieldInfo[] headerFields;
        private readonly int headerSize;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            panel.Paint += Panel_Paint;
            headerSize = sizeof(BMPHeader);
            headerFields = typeof(BMPHeader).GetFields();
        }

        private void openFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog()
            {
                InitialDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
            };
            var dialogResult = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
            if (dialogResult is DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ParseFile(openFileDialog.FileName);
            }
        }

        private void ParseFile(string filename)
        {
            using var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
            if (fileStream.Length <= headerSize)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect file format");
                return;
            }

            Span<byte> headerBuffer = stackalloc byte[headerSize];
            fileStream.ReadExactly(headerBuffer);

            fixed (byte* ptr = headerBuffer)
            {
                header = *(BMPHeader*)ptr;
            }

            foreach (var field in headerFields)
            {
                fileInfo.AppendText($"{field.Name}: {field.GetValue(header)}{Environment.NewLine}");
            }

            var pixelSize = header.bpp / 8;
            var rowSize = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)header.bpp * header.width / 32) * 4;
            var dataSizeCalculated = rowSize * header.height;
            var dataSizeFromHeader = header.image_size;
            var dataSizeStreamInfo = fileStream.Length - headerSize;

            if (dataSizeCalculated != dataSizeFromHeader || dataSizeFromHeader != dataSizeStreamInfo)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect file format");
                fileInfo.Clear();
                return;
            }


            imageData = new byte[header.height, header.width, pixelSize];
            fixed (byte* ptr = imageData)
            {
                for (int i = header.height - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    var rowPtr = new Span<byte>(ptr + (i * header.width * pixelSize), rowSize);
                    fileStream.ReadExactly(rowPtr);
                }
            }
            panel.Width = header.width;
            panel.Height = header.height;
            panel.Invalidate();
        }

        private void transformGrayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Parallel.For(0, header.height, (i) =>
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < header.width; j++)
                {
                    var grayPixel = 0.299 * imageData[i, j, 0] + 0.587 * imageData[i, j, 1] + 0.114 * imageData[i, j, 2];
                    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
                        imageData[i, j, c] = (byte)grayPixel;
                }
            });
            panel.Invalidate();
        }

        private void createBorderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const int BorderSize = 15;
            if (header.height < BorderSize * 2 || header.width < BorderSize * 2)
                return;

            var rnd = Random.Shared;
            
            var color = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(0, 255), rnd.Next(0, 255), rnd.Next(0, 255));

            for (int i = 0; i < BorderSize; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < header.width; j++)
                {
                    SetPixel(i, j, color);
                    SetPixel(header.height - i - 1, j, color);
                }

                for (int j = BorderSize; j < header.height - BorderSize; j++)
                {
                    SetPixel(j, i, color);
                    SetPixel(j, header.width - i - 1, color);
                }
            }
            panel.Invalidate();
        }

        private void SetPixel(int x, int y, Color color)
        {
            imageData[x, y, 0] = color.B;
            imageData[x, y, 1] = color.G;
            imageData[x, y, 2] = color.R;
        }

        private void Panel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (imageData is null)
                return;

            using var bmp = new Bitmap(header.width, header.height);
            var bits = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, header.width, header.height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            fixed (byte* ptr = imageData)
            {
                //bits.Scan0 = (nint)ptr; // works only when rows have no padding
                for (int i = 0; i < header.height; i++)
                {
                    byte* destRow = (byte*)bits.Scan0 + (i * bits.Stride);
                    byte* sourceRow = ptr + (i * header.width * 3);
                    Buffer.MemoryCopy(sourceRow, destRow, header.width * 3, header.width * 3);
                }
            }
            bmp.UnlockBits(bits);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

**Edit 1**: tried to create another image in paint, saved as 24bppRGB bmp format, size is 27x27. The program just closes without any exception or something after `bits.UnlockBits`. Also, tried debugging, not sure where can I see what's happening behind those classes

**Edit 2**: here's the header I'm using

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct BMPHeader
{
    public ushort type;
    public uint size;
    public ushort reserved1;
    public ushort reserved2;
    public uint offset;
    public uint dib_size;
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public ushort planes;
    public ushort bpp;
    public uint compression;
    public uint image_size;
    public uint x_ppm;
    public uint y_ppm;
    public uint num_colors;
    public uint important_colors;
};
```

**Edit 3**: I've tried now to write back opened file with this code (which looks similar to read):

```
    var writeFs = new FileStream("testWrite.bmp", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    writeFs.Write(headerBuffer);
    fixed (byte* ptr = imageData)
    {
        for (int i = header.height - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var rowPtr = new Span<byte>(ptr + (i * header.width * pixelSize), rowSize);
            writeFs.Write(rowPtr);
        }
    }
    writeFs.Close();
```

New file is correctly opened in a Windows viewing application.

**Edit 4**: I've made a progress in finding a failure. It was a 3D array which just used HxWx3 dimensions. Probably there's no way to take padding into account using 3D arrays and jagged 3D isn't an option too, since dimensions wouldn't be aligned in memory to operate with pointers, so I changed it to be a 2D array. Padded and unpadded images now both open correctly. However, the issue with application closes silently still persists. It happens only with small-sized bitmaps (around 150x150 and less), there's no exception happens or something, the app just closes after processing the `bits.UnlockBits` line (which I already mentioned in Edit 1), bigger images open no problems. Here's the updated code:

```
public sealed unsafe partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private byte[,] imageData;
    private BMPHeader header;

    private readonly FieldInfo[] headerFields;
    private readonly int headerSize;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        panel.Paint += Panel_Paint;
        headerSize = sizeof(BMPHeader);
        headerFields = typeof(BMPHeader).GetFields();
    }

    private void openFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog()
        {
            InitialDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
        };
        var dialogResult = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (dialogResult is DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ParseFile(openFileDialog.FileName);
        }
    }

    private void ParseFile(string filename)
    {
        using var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
        if (fileStream.Length <= headerSize)
        {
            return;
        }

        Span<byte> headerBuffer = stackalloc byte[headerSize];
        fileStream.ReadExactly(headerBuffer);

        fixed (byte* ptr = headerBuffer)
        {
            header = *(BMPHeader*)ptr;
        }

        foreach (var field in headerFields)
        {
            fileInfo.AppendText($"{field.Name}: {field.GetValue(header)}{Environment.NewLine}");
        }

        var pixelSize = header.bpp / 8;
        var rowSize = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)header.bpp * header.width / 32) * 4;
        var dataSizeCalculated = rowSize * header.height;
        var dataSizeFromHeader = header.image_size;
        var dataSizeStreamInfo = fileStream.Length - headerSize;

        if (dataSizeCalculated != dataSizeFromHeader || dataSizeFromHeader != dataSizeStreamInfo)
        {
            fileInfo.Clear();
            return;
        }


        imageData = new byte[header.height, rowSize]; //array is now 2D
        fixed (byte* ptr = imageData)
        {
            for (int i = header.height - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var rowPtr = new Span<byte>(ptr + i * rowSize, rowSize); //row pointer is based on rowSize now
                fileStream.ReadExactly(rowPtr);
            }
        }

        panel.Width = header.width;
        panel.Height = header.height;
        panel.Invalidate();
    }

    private void transformGrayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, header.height, (i) =>
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < header.width; j++)
            {
                var grayPixel = 0.299 * imageData[i, j * 3] + 0.587 * imageData[i, j * 3 + 1] + 0.114 * imageData[i, j * 3 + 2]; //fixed here
                for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
                    imageData[i, j * 3 + c] = (byte)grayPixel;
            }
        });
        panel.Invalidate();
    }

    private void createBorderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const int BorderSize = 15;
        if (header.height < BorderSize * 2 || header.width < BorderSize * 2)
            return;

        var rnd = Random.Shared;
        
        var color = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(0, 255), rnd.Next(0, 255), rnd.Next(0, 255));

        for (int i = 0; i < BorderSize; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < header.width; j++)
            {
                SetPixel(i, j, color);
                SetPixel(header.height - i - 1, j, color);
            }

            for (int j = BorderSize; j < header.height - BorderSize; j++)
            {
                SetPixel(j, i, color);
                SetPixel(j, header.width - i - 1, color);
            }
        }
        panel.Invalidate();
    }

    private void SetPixel(int x, int y, Color color)
    {
        imageData[x, y * 3] = color.B; //fixed here
        imageData[x, y * 3 + 1] = color.G;
        imageData[x, y * 3 + 2] = color.R;
    }

    private void Panel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (imageData is null)
            return;

        using var bmp = new Bitmap(header.width, header.height);
        var bits = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, header.width, header.height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        fixed (byte* ptr = imageData)
        {
            try
            {
                bits.Scan0 = (nint)ptr;
                bmp.UnlockBits(bits);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // doesn't fall here
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try debugging it with a handmade BMP that's very small.

Comment: You need to read the header in the file to determine the size.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: @jdweng yep, I'm reading header, updated the question with the struct I'm using. I also check in the code above size from header, ```Length-sizeof(BMPHeader)``` of ```FileStream``` and calculated rowSize multiplied by height. All three match

Comment: "when I try to open any file where row size isn't divisible by four"  The row stride is a multiple of four bytes, even if the width is odd.  Padding is added to make this true.  You seem aware that this is true in memory (comment about padding and use of `Stride` member), but neglected that it's true in the file as well.

Comment: @BenVoigt yep, I'm taking this into account while reading file (otherwise nothing worked at all). The problem is in ```Panel_Paint``` method inside ```fixed``` block. I can do either just commented line of code, which results in an no-padding image being displayed correctly, but padded image either shows in a weird fashion or crashes app silently. Or I can do an uncommented loop of ```MemoryCopy``` which works both for padded and no-padding images. I want the commented line to work for both cases too, since I don't want all the buffers to be copied just to show the picture

Comment: You're trying to use a fixed pointer after the fixed block ends.  That's forbidden.  There's a way to avoid a copy but overwriting the lockdata pointer is not it, and the pointer needs to remain pinned for the lifetime of the bitmap object.

Comment: @BenVoigt I get your point, but if I try to display a non-padded image (where row size is divisible by 4) with this code ```fixed (byte* ptr = imageData)
{
    bits.Scan0 = (nint)ptr;
}
bmp.UnlockBits(bits);
e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);``` it works perfectly fine. Also I do DrawImage after everything, which I believe still copies my bitmap to draw it to Panel, which I can't avoid anyway. The problem only occurs when I try to open a padded image. Not sure if this is a pinning issue, maybe I'm wrong. I also tried to move everything into fixed block, but no difference

Comment: The error is on following.  Converting to double a using ceiling doesn't make any sense.   The size should be exactly divisible by 32 : var rowSize = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)header.bpp * header.width / 32) * 4;

Comment: @jdweng if you remove double cast, you get a compile error of overload conflict between Ceiling method for doubles and for decimals, since both bpp and width are ints I had to cast something to either double or decimal to make it work. The expression is still exactly divisible. This is the formula from the Wikipedia link you provided above: "ImageWidth is expressed in pixels. The equation above uses the floor and ceiling functions."

Comment: Why would a ushort * int require you to cast to a double?  Why do you need ceiling?  Your issue is you are rounding up.

Comment: @jdweng how would I then fix the formula? if I do ```var rowSize = header.bpp * header.width / 32 * 4;``` directly, rowSize is calculated incorrectly. The formula with ceiling is taken directly from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_storage - those square brackets mean rounding with either ceiling, or +31 with floor. If I remove double cast from Ceiling, I get CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: Math.Ceiling(decimal) and Math.Ceiling(double)

Comment: header.width is already the ceiling which is the max width of any row.  It is the header of all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you just need to calculate the stride proper?
If so, you don't need any call to `Math`.

```cs
uint stride = (((header.biWidth * header.biBitPerPixel + 31) / 32) * 4);
```

Bitmap is a file format created by Microsoft and it works exclusively with `WORD` and `DWORD` types. A `WORD` is just a 16-bit datatype and a `DWORD` just a 32-bit datatype. Both are used to store anything that does not need a specific type. The pixels of a Bitmap are stored in DWORDS, hence the need to pad to 32-bit.

Now, what IS the `stride`?
The stride describes the number of bytes that it takes to store a single row of an image. A pixel can be black and white, only needing one byte, but it can also be RGB, needing 3 bytes, or, in the case of PNG files also be something like ARGB, needing 4 bytes. The 4th byte is used to store the alpha value (transparency).
Computers work very efficient if the data you provide is aligned to the address boundary which more often then not is 4-byte. Padding file data to that boundary makes processing that data faster as the computer has it 'easier'. The padding also allows the BMP file format to support a wide range of different color spaces.

#### BMP pixels are upside down

When you first implement a BMP parser you might notice that your pixel data is rotated 180 degree, why is that?

**It's for compatibility with OS/2**

In OS/2 [Presentation Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_Manager)  the y axis starts at the bottom left of your screen, meaning y increases towards the top of your screen. While mathematically correct I don't know of any other OS doing that. All others seem to start the y axis from the top left where y increases towards the bottom of your screen.

**Conclusion** You either need to rotate your pixel data, rotate inputs, or just read it from top to bottom and write the data from bottom to top.

Here is my basic implementation which I originally wrote in C, so this is a quick and dirty translation.

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct BITMAPHEADER
{
    public const int BITMAP_SIG = 0x4d42;

    public const int BFH_SIG           = 0x0000;
    public const int BFH_FILESIZE      = 0x0002;
    public const int BFH_RESERVED      = 0x0006;
    public const int BFH_DATAOFFSET    = 0x000a;

    public const int BFH_BYTECOUNT = 0x000e;
    public const int BFH_HEADERSIZE = BFH_BYTECOUNT * sizeof(byte);

    public const int BIH_SIZE              = 0x000e;
    public const int BIH_WIDTH             = 0x0012;
    public const int BIH_HEIGHT            = 0x0016;
    public const int BIH_PLANES            = 0x001a;
    public const int BIH_BPP               = 0x001c;
    public const int BIH_COMPRESSION       = 0x001e;
    public const int BIH_IMAGESIZE         = 0x0022;
    public const int BIH_XPIXELSPERM       = 0x0026;
    public const int BIH_YPIXELSPERM       = 0x002a;
    public const int BIH_COLORSUSED        = 0x002e;
    public const int BIH_IMPORTANTCOLORS   = 0x0032;

    public const int BIH_BYTECOUNT = 0x0028;
    public const int BIH_HEADERSIZE = BIH_BYTECOUNT * sizeof(byte);

    [FieldOffset(BFH_SIG)]
    public UInt16 bfSig;
    [FieldOffset(BFH_FILESIZE)]
    public UInt32 bfSize;
    [FieldOffset(BFH_RESERVED)]
    public UInt32 bfReserved;
    [FieldOffset(BFH_DATAOFFSET)]
    public UInt32 bfDataOffset;

    [FieldOffset(BIH_SIZE)]
    public UInt32 biSize;
    [FieldOffset(BIH_WIDTH)]
    public UInt32 biWidth;
    [FieldOffset(BIH_HEIGHT)]
    public UInt32 biHeight;
    [FieldOffset(BIH_PLANES)]
    public UInt16 biPlanes;
    [FieldOffset(BIH_BPP)]
    public UInt16 biBitPerPixel;
    [FieldOffset(BIH_COMPRESSION)]
    public UInt32 biCompression;
    [FieldOffset(BIH_IMAGESIZE)]
    public UInt32 biImageSize;
    [FieldOffset(BIH_XPIXELSPERM)]
    public UInt32 biXpixelsPerM;
    [FieldOffset(BIH_YPIXELSPERM)]
    public UInt32 biYpixelsPerM;
    [FieldOffset(BIH_COLORSUSED)]
    public UInt32 biColorsUsed;
    [FieldOffset(BIH_IMPORTANTCOLORS)]
    public UInt32 biImportantColors;
}


public static class BitmapHeaderParser
{
    private static BITMAPHEADER BufferToHeader(byte[] buffer)
    {
        GCHandle gchHeader = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        BITMAPHEADER hdr = Marshal.PtrToStructure<BITMAPHEADER>(gchHeader.AddrOfPinnedObject());
        gchHeader.Free();

        return hdr;
    }

    public static BITMAPHEADER GetHeader(string fileName)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
        using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            buffer = new byte[BITMAPHEADER.BFH_HEADERSIZE + BITMAPHEADER.BIH_HEADERSIZE];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        
        BITMAPHEADER header = default(BITMAPHEADER);            
        try {
            header = BufferToHeader(buffer);                
        }
        catch {
            header = default(BITMAPHEADER);
        }

        if (header.bfSig != BITMAPHEADER.BITMAP_SIG) {
            throw new InvalidDataException("Invalid header signature");
        }
        return header;
    }


    public static byte[][] LoadBitmapPixel(string fileName, BITMAPHEADER header)
    {
        uint h = header.biHeight;
        uint stride = (((header.biWidth * header.biBitPerPixel + 31) / 32) * 4);

        byte[][] pixels = new byte[h][];
        using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            stream.Seek(header.bfDataOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            for (uint y = 0, ydest = h - 1; y < h; y++, ydest--)
            {
                pixels[ydest] = new byte[stride];
                stream.Read(pixels[ydest], 0, (int)stride);
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(stream.Position);
        }
        return pixels;
    }
}
```

I am lazy so here is a example of the pixels being written as ASCII in the console:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var header = BitmapHeaderParser.GetHeader(@"C:\Users\user\pictures\bmp_24.bmp");
    var px = BitmapHeaderParser.LoadBitmapPixel(@"C:\Users\user\pictures\bmp_24.bmp", header);

    int xIncrement = header.biBitPerPixel / 8;
    for (int y = 0; y < header.biHeight; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < px[y].Length; x+=xIncrement)
        {
            float avg = (
                px[y][x + 2] * 0.299f +
                px[y][x + 1] * 0.587f +
                px[y][x + 0] * 0.114f
            );
            
            if (avg > 120) {
                Console.Write("@");
            }
            else if (avg < 120 && avg > 70) {
                Console.Write("o");
            }
            else {
                Console.Write(".");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I have used this image for testing the translated code: https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/data/bmp/bmp_24.bmp

[image]

Comment: Your picture is correctly displayed in my code from edit 4 also (besides it has header image_size = 0 which caused my size check to pop, but disabling it fixes), but this is 200x200 image, and I now have a problem with only images less than around 150x150, which I stated out in Edit 4. So the problem now is narrowed down to assigning a pointer to my pixel array to Scan0 pointer leads to silent crash of application. I tried your suggestion with another stride formula, but nothing changed - bigger pictures still shows perfect, smaller pictures lesser than 150x150 still silently crashed app

Comment: Checked eventlog now, it says Application Error for module C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll version 10.0.22621.1485, exception code 0xc0000374, error offset 0x000000000010be19. It happens each time I try to parse small image, and doesn't happen when I try to parse any other image larger than 150x150 or so threshold.

Comment: @SelfishCrawler Since the issue is in your code and your code only you don't need to check Eventlog. My example works fine with images smaller than 150x150. Start debugging and if you don't know how, google it. I don't mean to offend you but if you have a debugger on your hand it is important to learn how to use it and there are many great examples on the web! You need to check where exactly your code fails. But my guess is that your code fails within your `ParseFile` function? Isolate the error first, then step through your code while debugging and then try to fix it :)

Comment: @SelfishCrawler Don't use fixed and pointers so much throughout your code. Only use them for short periods in your code and only when really necessary. You are working with unsafe code and pointers in managed code. A lot can go wrong when doing that. Refrain from using member variables especially in this context as you won't know which function is locking or altering your member.

Comment: The error occurs in ```Panel_Paint``` method when I do ```bits.UnlockBits```. And when I step to it, nothing happens, the debugging session is just over, no exception or something. I'm trying to use debugger and know the basics at least, but this situation is weird for me. I've compared bits.Stride and my calculated stride and it always matches, and several extra things aswell. And it never crash on large images, that's what is the most weird thing for me...

Comment: @SelfishCrawler I won't try your code as it is a WinForm and I won't build a form just to test some code. Change `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb` in your `Panel_Paint` to `bmp.PixelFormat`. Your test file might not be 24bpp and that will crash your code.

Comment: Changing PixelFormat broken everything, as bmp in Panel_Paint is a blank target bmp to which I wanna put my image buffer. My picture is definitely 24bbp, I create it in Paint and save as 24bit bmp. I even keep it open, when I increase it's size, my app opens it correctly, but when I decrease the size back, to less than 150x, it starts to crash again, and after increasing size it begins to open correctly again). Also if I try to write my buffer back to another file (i.e. create FileStream, write headerBuffer, then row by row write all buffer), it opens correctly in Windows viewer application.

Comment: I've actually found an easier solution, which probably worked now. There's a constructor in bitmap, which takes Scan0 directly and seems to not reallocate buffer. So this ```using var bmp = new Bitmap(header.width, header.height, stride, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, (nint)ptr); e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);``` seems to be working fine and don't even require to lock bits, instead just taking a pointer to buffer. Dunno what's the actual difference